# Issue with removing selected option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some product filters for a collection. The filters are options within a select. Now I'm trying to implement that when the "All" option is selected it removes all the other selected options.

This is the code

```
  <select class="coll-filter" id="select-1">
    <option value="" class="test">All</option>
    {% for tag in tags %}
    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected class="test2">{{ tag }}</option>
    {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}
    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" class="test2">{{ tag }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

And the JS

```
        $('#select-1').change(function() {
    if($(".test").is(':selected')){
       $('#select-1').find(".test2").remove(':selected');
    };
  });
```

With this it removes the select of the first option that is selected, but not the second one so seem it only fires on the first selected option. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and give upvote it to help other programmers for finding a solution when they have same issue. The majority of programmers see accepted or upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your existing code is working for 1st option too. Because change event occurs on select element, not on option.

I have applied the generic changes for your code and now you can see when ALL is selected, all others are unselected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showResults();
});

function showResults() {
  var options = [];
  $.each($("#select-1 option:selected"), function() {
    options.push($(this).val());
  });
  alert("You have selected options - " + options.join(", "));
}

$('#select-1').change(function() {
  if ($('#select-1 option[value=all]').is(':selected')) {
    alert('i am here');
    //$('#select-1').find(".test2").remove(':selected');
    //$('select-1 option[value=all]').attr('selected','selected');
    $('#select-1').val('all');
  } else {
    showResults();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p> <i> Press control key (Ctrl) to select multiple values: </i> </p>
<select class="coll-filter" id="select-1" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option value="all" class="test" selected>All</option>
  <option value="1" class="test" selected> 1 </option>
  <option value="2" class="test3"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3" class="test4" selected> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this

```
$('#select-1 option').change(function(){
   if($(".test").is(':selected')){
  $('#select-1').children...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set "-1" to value of `All` option and do it like this:

```
$('#select-1').change(function() {
if($(this).val()== "-1")
  $(this).find('option').not($('.test')).removeAttr("selected");
});
```

**[Online demo (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/wgpxq0ts/10/)**